# Integrating gitlab and keycloak

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab, keycloak, kubernetes-helm, host

I am trying to link keycloak installed with helm and gitlab.
The provider was provided using omniauth.

```
{
   name: "openid_connect", # do not change this parameter
   label: "Keycloak", # optional label for login button, defaults to "Openid Connect"
   args: {
         name: "openid_connect",
         scope: ["openid", "profile", "email"],
         response_type: "code",
         issuer:  "http://keycloak.cicd.kr/realms/cicd",
         client_auth_method: "basic",
         discovery: true,
         uid_field: "preferred_username",
         pkce: true,
         client_options: {
           identifier: "gitlab",
           secret: "oHvUlDbrgpvfy5qLO9dVOZ1jOE2Zsy3L",
           scheme: http,
           port: 80,
           redirect_uri: "https://gitlab.cicd.kr/users/auth/openid_connect/callback",
           authorization_endpoint: "http://keycloak.cicd.kr/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
           token_endpoint: "http://keycloak.kr/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token",
           userinfo_endpoint: "http://keycloak.kr/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo"
         }
   }
}
```

```
NAME    NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
gitlab  gitlab          5               2023-10-16 13:35:49.332146052 +0900 KST deployed        gitlab-6.8.0    15.8.0
```

```
NAME            NAMESPACE       REVISION        UPDATED                                 STATUS          CHART           APP VERSION
keycloak        keycloak        4               2023-10-16 11:36:23.137776603 +0900 KST deployed        keycloak-15.0.4 21.1.1
```

However, if you call keycloak from the UI, an error occurs.
This seems to be because there is no host information for keycloak in the gitlab pod.

```
Could not authenticate you from OpenIDConnect because "Getaddrinfo: name or service not known (keycloak.cicd.kr:443)".
```

I came up with a few solutions, but I don't know how.
How to add hostAliases to helm gitlab configuration